# What are some LED technology for one dimensional coherent light emission?

Tags: led, infrared, laser

I need to emit a unidirectional infrared pattern, i.e. the emission cone should have small angle on one dimension and large angle on the other one (basically laser-like in one dimension and normal light on the other). I tried to illustrate this in the image below (alpha should be much bigger than beta, e.g. alpha = 90 degrees and beta = 4 degrees)

I looked into laser diode arrays, but majority of them are high power, which makes them hazardous and thus not suitable for my application.

Covering a normal LED with a mask is something I though about, but it is rather difficult to realize it with the tools that I have. It also reduces the intensity of the infrared, which I wish to avoid. Another approach is to mechanically sweep a low intensity laser diode, using an dc motor, but doesn't fit into my list of requirements (wrt size and cost)

So mainly, I need to find an LED which optically focuses the emitter light in one direction and not the other.

Do you know of such LED (manufacturer, part number, ...), or any other solutions that can fulfill the following requirements: low cost, easy to reproduce in large quantities (i.e. 100s), and safe for usage without any protection glass and alike.

[image: alpha >> beta, e.g. alpha = 90 degrees and beta = 4 degrees]

Comment: You can get low-power IR laser diodes with collimator optics. I'm confused about the presence of both alpha and beta - you want a lightly illuminated area with a bright spot in the middle?

Comment: Can LEDs really emit coherent light? I always thought only lasers are able to do that. (I distinguish a LED from a laser diode, as they are a bit different)

Comment: @pjc50 I think he's after projecting a single line, from that picture I'd guess at vertically.

Comment: @pjc50 the picture is not accurate. I am after projecting a line, as Majenko put it nicely. What kind of collimator should I look for whic produce such pattern? Any specific term you can think of?

Comment: Cylindrical lens: http://www.newport.com/Beam-Shaping-with-Cylindrical-Lenses/144888/1033/content.aspx (I have a cheap laser spirit level that produces a red line, which sounds like what you want)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very difficult to collimate an LED output efficiently, and LED output is not coherent.

But, many laser diodes naturally emit a pattern like you drew. The reason is that the laser cavity is typically several microns across in the horizontal direction, but only a fraction of a micron tall in the vertical dimension. Due to diffraction, this results in an emitted beam with very large divergence vertically (like 40 degree full-angle) and much less divergence horizontally (10, 15, 20 degrees, maybe). For example, see these specs for a 10 mW laser from ThorLabs:

[image]

If a radially symetric output beam is needed, special output optics (like the cylindrical lenses mentioned in other answers) are used to correct for the problem.

So what you might really want is just an IR laser diode with no such corrective optics, or with corrective optics only to collimate the beam horizontally.

If you search "line-laser IR" you might also find some devices pre-packaged with suitable optics.

One more note, you expressed some concern about

> high power, which makes them hazardous

Realize that the eye safety of a laser depends on how much power the laser can deliver to the roughly 1 mm<sup>2</sup> aperture of a human eye. A laser emitting in a long line will only deliver a small fraction of its power to any particular 1 mm<sup>2</sup> spot, so the danger is much reduced. Of course, while you're working on the system if you might get your face within a few inches of the laser, or look at it through magnifying optics, you will want to be very cautious to keep the laser off or reduce its output power at that time.

Answer (score 1):

A cylindrical lens focuses the light in only one direction. If you place it "one focal length" in front of your LED you will get the desired emission cone.

Compared to lasers, LEDs emit from a rather large surface, which limits by how much the light can be collimated.